# Reference for Mean Value Theorem in several variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let $f\in C^{1}(\Omega)$ where $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^{d}$ is a convex open set. Let $y,z\in\Omega$. We have, for some $\alpha\in[0,1]$:

$$\vert f(y)-f(z)\vert\le\left\vert\nabla f(\alpha y+(1-\alpha)z)\right\vert\cdot\Vert y-z\Vert$$

In particular, if $f$ is considered as a function of only one variable (for simplicity, say the last one, i.e. $x_{d}$) with $d-1$ parameters, we have:

\begin{align*}
&\vert f(x_{1},\dots,x_{d-1},y_{d})-f(x_{1},\dots,x_{d-1},z_{d})\vert\\
&\hspace{2em}\le\left\vert\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{d}}(x_{1},\dots,x_{d-1},\alpha y_{d}+(1-\alpha)z_{d})\right\vert\cdot\vert y_{d}-z_{d}\vert\\
&\hspace{2em}\le\sup_{\hat{x}_{d}}\left\vert\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{d}}(x_{1},\dots,x_{d-1},\hat{x}_{d})\right\vert\cdot\vert y_{d}-z_{d}\vert
\end{align*}

This makes sense and follows quite directly from the unidimensional version of the theorem, if I am not mistaken. However, I have seen the following, more general version of the theorem and I would like to know if there is some reference about it:

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be an open set and let $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^{m}$ differentiable. Then, for any compact $K\subset\Omega$ and any $x,y\in K$, we have

$$\Vert f(x)-f(y)\Vert_{m}\le\sup_{K}\left\Vert\partial f\right\Vert_{m}\cdot\Vert x-y\Vert_{n}$$

And, to be honest, I don't even get how I have to interpret this expression. Can I take any partial derivative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression $\partial f$ refers to the Jacobian matrix of $f$: $\partial f=(\partial f_i/\partial x_j)_{1\leq i\leq m,1\leq j\leq n}$. The mean value theorem in several variables says that 
$$ f(x+h)-f(x)=\left(\int_0^1\partial f(x+th)\,dt\right) h,$$
assuming that $x+th\in K$ for all $0\leq t\leq 1$. Then:
$$ \Vert f(x+h)-f(x)\Vert= \left\Vert \int_0^1\partial f(x+th)h\,dt\right\Vert\leq \int_0^1\Vert \partial f(x+th)\Vert\Vert h\Vert\,dt\leq M\Vert h\Vert, $$
where $M=\sup_{a\in K}\Vert \partial f(a)\Vert$.

If $f\in C^1(\Omega)$, then $\Vert\partial f\Vert$ is continuous from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and therefore the supremum $M$ is finite.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is a very precise and concise answer.