# Prove that $\Vert f(b)-f(a)-f'(a)(b-a) \Vert\leq \sup_{x\in [a,b]} \Vert f''(x)\Vert\Vert b-a\Vert^2$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, normed-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be an open set in $\Bbb{R}^n$ and $f:\Omega\to \Bbb{R}^m $ be of class $\Bbb{C}^2.$ Let $a,b$ be in $\Omega$ such that $[a,b]\subset \Omega.$ Prove that 
\begin{align}\Vert f(b)-f(a)-f'(a)(b-a) \Vert\leq \sup_{x\in [a,b]} \Vert f''(x)\Vert\Vert b-a\Vert^2.\end{align}
where
$$f'(a)(b-a)=\big<\nabla f(x),(b-a)\big>=\sum^{n}_{k=1}\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_k}(a)(b_k-a_k).$$

I  think the idea of Mean Value Theorem for $C'$ functions in $\Bbb{R}^n$ ([Reference for Mean Value Theorem in several variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1718611/reference-for-mean-value-theorem-in-several-variables?rq=1)) will help me in showing it but I don't know how to! Please, can anyone show me a proof or reference?

Comment: What is $c\in [a,b]$ for a function $f:\Omega\to \Bbb{R}^m $ and $\Omega\subset \Bbb{R}^n$? And how $f''(c)$ is defined?

Comment: It is still confusing, you mix notations specific for single-variable calculus with multivariable calculus ... like $c\in [a,b] \subset \Omega \subset \mathbb{R^{n}}$

Comment: Is this a question from a text book or a homework? Or are you trying to improvise? Any references will help to improve the question ...

Comment: Well, for now, the quickest fix is to replace $\mathbb{R^m}$ and $\mathbb{R^n}$ with just $\mathbb{R}$ and remove the multivariable calculus tag. And the answer below becomes a valid answer.

Comment: In this case, you need to replace $f'(a)$ with [gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient) and explain how $f'(a)(b-a)$ works given $f'(a) \in \mathbb{R^m}$ and $b-a \in \mathbb{R^n}$ for $n\ne m$.

Comment: @rtybase: Can't visit the page! However, do you mean that the question is not correct in its present form?

Comment: This is the page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient ... the question is confusing in the present form. It is not clear what $f'(a)$ is for a multivariable function from $\mathbb{R^n}$ to $\mathbb{R^m}$ and how product of 2 vectors from different vector spaces is defined (i.e. $f'(a)(b-a)$). Also, notation like $x \in [a,b]$ is not clear in terms of $a,b \in \mathbb{R^n}$.

Comment: @rtybase: I have finally added what you requested of me! Hope it's correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$g(x)=f(b)-f(x)-f'(x)(b-x).$$
Note that $f'(x)$ here is defined to be the $m\times n$ matrix with entries $\partial f_i(x)/\partial x_j$, where $f(x)=(f_1(x),\ldots, f_m(x))$. Therefore, the product $f'(x)(b-x)$ is understood as the matrix product of $f'(x)$ and $b-x$. The result is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^m$ with makes $g(x)$ a meaningful function from $\Omega$ into $\mathbb{R}^m$. The derivative of $g(x)$ is again an $m\times n$ matrix whose $ij$-th entry is given by 
$$-\sum_{k}\dfrac{\partial f_i(x)}{\partial x_j\partial x_k}(b_k-x_k).$$
Then
$$\|g'(x)\|^2=\sum_{i,j} \|\sum_{k}\dfrac{\partial f_i(x)}{\partial x_j\partial x_k}(b_k-x_k) \|^2 \leq \left (\sum_{i,j,k} \left \|\dfrac{\partial f_i(x)}{\partial x_j\partial x_k} \right \|^2 \right ) \|b-x\|^2.$$

It follows from this and substitution in the inequality
$$\|g(b)-g(a)\| \leq \sup_{c\in [a,b]}\|g'(x)\|\|b-a\|,$$
that 
$$\|f(b)-f(a)-f'(a)(b-a)\| \leq \sup_{x\in [a,b]} \left (\sum_{i,j,k} \left \|\dfrac{\partial f_i(x)}{\partial x_j\partial x_k} \right \|^2 \right )^{1/2} \|b-a\|^2.$$
A reasonable definition for $\|f''(x)\|$ would be the triple sum given above and I assumed that's what it is meant by it.

Comment: Thanks, but I edited some things!

Comment: What is the idea behind choosing your $g(t)?$

Comment: @Marco: Thanks Marco!

Comment: I don't understand your explanation at this point. Please can you explain again? \begin{align}\|f(b)-f(a)-f'(a)(b-a)\| \leq \sup_{x\in [a,b]} \left (\sum_{i,j,k} \left \|\dfrac{\partial f_i(x)}{\partial x_j\partial x_k} \right \|^2 \right )^{1/2} \|b-a\|^2.\end{align}

Comment: That inequality follows by substitution into the previous inequality.

Comment: If I may ask, what guided our choice of $g(x)=f(b)-f(x)-f'(x)(b-x)?$ Then, if we differentiate, do we have $g'(x)=-f''(x)(b-x)$ or $g'(x)=-f'(x)-f''(x)(b-x)?$ I don't understand, kindly explain to me. I need to also explain to some people too! Thanks!

Comment: The choice of $g(x)$ is a usual trick for a repeated use of the inequality $\|g(b)-g(a)\| \leq \sup \|g(x)\| \|b-a\|$. One has to be careful defining $f''(x)$ in higher dimensions. That's why we look at $g(x)$ as a function from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ and its derivative will be an $m\times n$ matrix. Derivative of that matrix is taken component by component and in each component one uses sum and product rules. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it does! Kindly check, isn't the matrix $g'(x)$ supposed to be double and not triple?

Comment: Each entry of the matrix $g'(x)$ is a sum, and so its norm square is a triple sum. The norm of a matrix $A$ being defined as $\|A\|^2=tr(AA^T)=\sum_{i,j}\|A_{ij}\|^2.$