# Proof explanation: Prove that $\Vert f(b)-f(a)-f'(a)(b-a) \Vert\leq \sup_{x\in [a,b]} \Vert f''(x)\Vert\Vert b-a\Vert^2$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

Two days ago, I asked a question
[Prove that $\Vert f(b)-f(a)-f'(a)(b-a) \Vert\leq \sup_{x\in [a,b]} \Vert f''(x)\Vert\Vert b-a\Vert^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2885937/prove-that-vert-fb-fa-fab-a-vert-leq-sup-x-in-a-b-vert-fx) but was answered just once. However, I am finding it hard to understand the proof provided.

Please, I'll need thorough explanation or another proof. As to the proof, I don't understand

1. why triple sum was used and not double.
2. If we differentiate $g(x)=f(b)-f(x)-f'(x)(b-x)$, what do we get?

I am asking because I find it hard to comprehend the proof. Please, can anyone explain these to me? Alternative proofs are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you re-asking the same very question? I mentioned your previous question was confusing because of bad notations. And again you have accepted an answer that doesn't take multivariable calculus into account. Why did you accept the answer to the previous question if it wasn't clear to you?

Comment: @rtybase: I'm sorry for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall Taylor's formula for $g\colon[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ twice differentiable
$$
g(1)=g(0)+g'(0)+\int_0^1g^{\prime\prime}(s)(1-s)\mathrm{d}s;
$$
(I will prove this ad hoc bellow). Now apply this to the function $g(t):= f((1-t)a+tb)$ for $t\in[0,1]$ to get your answer:

**Answer**: By the chain rule:
$$
f(b)=f(a)+f^\prime(a)(b-a)+\int_0^1(1-t)\langle a-b,f^{\prime\prime}((1-t)a+tb)(a-b)\rangle\mathrm{d}t
$$
so that by the triangle inequality for integrals
$$
\|f(b)-f(a)-f^\prime(a)(b-a)\|\leq \int_0^1 (1-t)\|f^{\prime\prime}((1-t)a+tb)(b-a)\|\|b-a\|\mathrm{d} t\\
\leq \sup_{x\in[a,b]}\|f^{\prime\prime}(x)(b-a)\|\|b-a\|\int_0^1 (1-t)\mathrm{d}t\\
=\frac{1}{2}\sup_{x\in[a,b]}\|f^{\prime\prime}(x)(b-a)\|\|b-a\|
$$
where in the first inequality we applied Cauchy-Schwarz. Now it seems to me that one can get $\frac{1}{2}$ as the best constant here (clearly optimal if $n=1$), but the answer is, in any case, quite irrelevant as on finite dimensional spaces all norms are equivalent and you do not state clearly what is the norm on $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ (i.e., where $f^{\prime\prime}$ sits). However, let's say that we work with Euclidean (square) norms only. Let $M\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $x\in\mathbb{R^n}$. Then, again by Cauchy-Schwarz,
$$
\|Mx\|^2=\sum_{i=1}^n (ROW_jM\cdot x)^2\leq \sum_{i=1}^n \|ROW_jM\|^2\| x\|^2=\|M\|^2\|x\|^2,
$$
so that we can substitute $M=f^{\prime\prime}(a)$, $x=b-a$ to get
$$
\|f(b)-f(a)-f^\prime(a)(b-a)\|\leq\frac{1}{2}\sup_{x\in[a,b]}\|f^{\prime\prime}(x)\|\|b-a\|^2.
$$
**Proof of Taylor's formula**: Let
$$
I=\int_0^1\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}[(1-s)g^\prime(s)]\mathrm{d}s,
$$
which we compute in two ways. First, by FTC
$$
I=-g^\prime(0).
$$
Second, by the product rule and linearity of integration,
$$
I=\int_0^1-g^\prime(s)\mathrm{d}s+\int_0^1(1-s)g^{\prime\prime}(s)\mathrm{d}s=-g(1)+g(0)+\int_0^1(1-s)g^{\prime\prime}(s)\mathrm{d}s.
$$
**Minor appendix**: As it stands, my proof tackles the case $m=1$; however, it is completely trivial to extend it (though it is not entirely clear how/if the constant suffers; this of course depends on your choices of norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$).

**Philosophy**: This problem is in any case 1-dimensional; the LHS is the first order Taylor polynomial with step $b-a$, so of course it gives an error $o(|b-a|^2)$.

Comment: Sorry, if we differentiate \begin{align}f^{\prime}((1-t)a+tb)(a-b)\end{align}, won't we arrive at \begin{align}f^{\prime\prime}((1-t)a+tb)(a-b)^2?\end{align}

Comment: $(a-b)$ is a vector