# What is the maximum of the function $|(e^a - e^b)/(a-b)|$ over all values $a,b$ belonging to a complex ball?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $B(0,r)$ be the closed convex ball of radius $r$ in the complex plane. I want to find an upper bound on the quantity
$$
\sup_{a,b \in B(0,r)} \left | \frac{e^a - e^b}{a-b} \right |.
$$
My attempt was to apply the mean value theorem but this seems only to work with real-valued functions.

Comment: The version of the MVT that may be used for your problem is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1718611/121671)

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is differentiable and its domain is convex, then$$\left|\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\right|\leqslant|f'(c)|,$$for some $c$ in the line segment from $a$ to $b$. So, if $a,b\in B(0,r)$,$$\left|\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\right|\leqslant\sup_{c\in B(0,r)}|e^c|=\sup_{c\in B(0,r)}e^{\operatorname{Re}c}=e^r.$$